# Use Python and BeautifulSoup to access title attribute of tags in web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and i am trying to retrieve all the titles from a particular url, but i am unable to do so. The code is getting compiled without any errors, but still i don't get the output.

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def test_function(num):
    url = "https://www.zomato.com/chennai/restaurants?buffet=1&page=" +       
    str(num)
    source_code = requests.get(url) 
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll('title'):
        print(link)
test_function(1)
```

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the `title` attribute?  As you have it `findall` will get the items with the tag `title`.  Since this is not a common `html` tag, that is likely why you are getting nothing.

Comment: no,the string associated to the title.

Comment: what do you mean by `all the titles`? do you mean all the text within `<h1>`, `<h2>`, ... tags?

Comment: all the titles in a particular webpage. the html tag is <a class = "" href = "" title = "">asdf</a> I need the value within title = "".

Comment: so you want the title attribute of all html tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the title of the page you can simply use:

```
soup.title.string
```

However, it seems that instead of actually wanting the page title, you want the attribute of any tag that contains title. If you wish to get the title attribute for each tag (if it exists) then you can do this:

```
for tag in soup.findAll():
    try:
        print(tag['title'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

This will print all the titles for tags in the page. We look through ALL tags, try and print its title value, if there is none we will get a KeyError, we then do nothing with the error!

There is also the issue of not passing a user-agent with the request. This site will give a 500 error if you do not. I've added in the code to do that below.

With your code that would be

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"}

def test_function(num):
    url = "https://www.zomato.com/chennai/restaurants?buffet=1&page=" +       
        str(num)
    source_code = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS) 
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for tag in soup.findAll():
        try:
            print(tag['title'])
        except KeyError:
            pass

test_function(1)
```

Comment: Matt, do u want me to use this in place of soup.findAll('title')

Comment: Matt i get the "[Finished in 6.5s]" in the output console. But don't find any titles.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that, I've included an additional header in my code otherwise you'll get a 500 error!

Comment: now it seems to be working fine. Thank a lot Matt. Why did we have to introduce the header?

Comment: Great. If you can upvote/mark the answer as correct, I'd appreciate that. Some website require you to pass certain information with the request to access a web page, we forwarded user-agent details so that we appear to be using Firefox to make the request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add header to get response 200 then do the same you do.

```
def test_function(num):
    url = "https://www.zomato.com/chennai/restaurants"
    params = {'buffet': 1, 'page': num}
    header = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
              'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=header)
    plain_text = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll('title'):
        print(link.text)


test_function(1)
Restaurants in Chennai serving Buffet - Zomato
```

Comment: but the intention is to get all the title attributes in the page and that page has many. <a class = "" href = "" title = "">asdf</a> I need the value within title = ""